# alertController only displays on the first page it was initalized on

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a weird problem with the alertController in Ionic.

Let me describe it and then I will lay out my code.

I have an app in Ionic with tabs. So lets say I reload my app and land on Tab 1, I click a button and get an alert on that page. Then if I were to navigate to Tab 2, click another button to get a different alert. That alert doesn't show up on Tab 2. But if I were to navigate to Tab 1, it will be there.

Here is my code for Tab 1

```
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Approved!',
        backdropDismiss: false,
        message:
            'Your application has been approved! You may start shopping now',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Shop!',
                handler: async () => {
                    this.util.navigateRoot('/shop');
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    await alert.present();
```

And Tab 2

```
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Submitted!',
        backdropDismiss: false,
        message:
            'Awaiting approval',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Shop!',
                handler: async () => {
                    this.util.navigateRoot('/shop');
                },
            },
        ],
    });

    await alert.present();
```

And of course I am importing alertController into the constructor of the component

I have done so much searching on this and no one seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this bug in stackblitz. 
Just Fork it and make your own stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-v8-tabs-sample

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, I ended up finding the solution @Na

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I was using  incorrectly on several pages. After I put it on the root app.component.html and removed the other ones, everything worked